# firefox unload event POST fails

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to know what is this 200 code mean it is in gray color, please see the screenshot.

[image]This POST request is a result of unload event, but for some reason I do not receive it on the server. I already checked the MDN documentation for this from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) unfortunately it does not describe this particular one i.e. solid gray dot with code 200, please see screenshot.

Comment: Solid gray means it's being loaded. It will change to other icons eventually.

Comment: @Raptor i had preserve logs on and I could see It stayed gray forever, and I received nothing on the serverside. also notice that the first request to the same url(marked with green) was successful

Comment: "It stayed gray **forever**": isn't there supposed to be timeout value for the request? did you set one? Is it the whole page `unload` or an element's one?

Comment: Check the access log & error log of your web server. It might receive something, but failed to respond

Comment: at the moment no timeout for the POST request and it is a request trieggered by whole page unload event